# Grunt: what is the purpose of cwd?

Tags: gruntjs

I know `cwd` stands for "current working directory", but what I don't understand is why is has to be included in the gruntfile.js.

Won't the script run always in the current working directory? Why would you need to change or specify another one?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

grunt.js resides in the root of our project.

`cwd` is the path where grunt looks for the files matching the pattern in `src` and performs operations on. It can be an img folder in the current project root or a script folder in the current project root.

In other words, `cwd` is the parent folder of `src` files. It might not be the root folder of the root of the current project but a child of it.

Hope this helps answer your question.

Comment: Very useful. Thank you!